# Redirecting IP (8.8.8.8 to ISP's dns) using netgear router with busybox

Tags: networking, router, dns, redirection

Here's the high level version of my problem: I have a chromecast and my ISP blocks all DNS traffic that's not theirs. I want to redirect 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 to my ISP's DNS.

Information:

Router model -  WNDR3400v3

Firmware version - V1.0.0.22_1.0.29

**I can't flash DD-WRT because it's not supported on this model.**

I enabled the telnet console and here are the commands I have available.

```
. : break cd chdir continue eval exec exit export false hash
help local pwd read readonly return set shift source times trap
true type ulimit umask unset wait

ash          echo         ip           ls           ping         umount
busybox      egrep        ipaddr       mkdir        ping6        wps_ap
cat          fgrep        iplink       mknod        ps           wps_monitor
chmod        grep         iproute      mount        pwd          zcat
cp           gunzip       iprule       netstat      rm
df           gzip         iptunnel     nice         rmdir
eapd         hostname     kill         ntfs-3g      sh

find      killall   nslookup  tftp      top       uptime    wet

acos_init              erase                  pppdv6
acos_service           getchksum              preinit
autoconfig_wan_down    gpio                   rc
autoconfig_wan_up      halt                   read_bd
bd                     hotplug                reboot
burn5gpass             hotplug2               reset_no_reboot
burn5gssid             htmlget                restart_all_processes
burn_hw_rev            ifconfig               rmmod
burnboardid            init                   route
burncode               insmod                 routerinfo
burnethermac           ipv6-conntab           showconfig
burnpass               leddown                sysctl
burnpin                ledup                  ubdcmd
burnrf                 lsmod                  udevtrigger
burnsku                mount.ntfs-3g          uptime
burnsn                 ntpclient              version
burnssid               parser                 write
dhcp6c_down            poweroff
dhcp6c_up              pppd
```

Here's the contents of `/etc`

```
group           igmprt.conf     ld.so.cache     passwd          small.ico
hotplug2.rules  iproute2        ld.so.conf      ppp             udev
icon.ico        large.ico       lld2d.conf      resolv.conf
```

Any ideas?